# window.speechSynthesis.getVoices doesn't work when reloading page with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I'm using Next.js and I'm trying to access SpeechSynthesis browser's API:
`window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()`

Since I'm using Next.js, I put the call to `window` into a `useEffect`, and it works fine on first load.

```
//...
  const [voices, setVoices] = useState<SpeechSynthesisVoice[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setVoices(window.speechSynthesis.getVoices());
  }, []);
//...
```

But the weirdest of things happen when I reload the page after. I get a misleading error in the console and suddenly `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` returns nothing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV1N3.png)

Do you know why? What should i do differently?

I put my code into a Next.js temnplate in CodeSandBox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/speechsynthesis-getvoices-reload-issue-kuittt?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A17%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A9%2C%22startColumn%22%3A17%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A9%7D%5D) for you to take a look.

Thanks in advance for yuour help

I tried putting the function in useCallback, useMemo... but nothing worked.

Comment: absolute mind boggling issue. On my machine it's actually the other way around where it returns an empty array on load. It seems that I need to run getVoices twice to get a result?
As quick fix I created a button for 'load voices'